# css menu submenu horizontal

Tags: html, css

How can I create css menu and submenu like this.

When I click or move mouse over the menu, It has a small icon at bottom

[image]

Comment: **What have you tried???**

Comment: @Charles Tian: This is what I can do. http://jsfiddle.net/furyfish/yPXbT/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li><a href=#><span>Main item text</span><span class="bullet"></span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href=#><span>Sub item text</span><span class="bullet"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.nav li ul { position: absolute; display: none; }
ul.nav li { float: left; }
ul.nav li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

Ofcourse besides that you must style list properly.
Here you can try how it work with bullet http://jsfiddle.net/9r4Lf/1/